# Google Store version of my app crashes

Tags: android, google-play, splash-screen, classnotfoundexception

I;m not sure why but the Google play version of my app crashes upon opening when the normal apk doesn't. looking at the logcat sent back by a crash report it seems like it cant find the splash-screen class. which is weird. i have not touched the splash screen at all and the app worked before when got of google play.

i changed the version number from version 1 to version 2 since i couldn't have the same version number but would that be why it doesnt work?

here is the logcat from the crash report. i cannot duplicate this error when testing it in debug mode

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.LEEADS/com.LEEADS.timestableseasy.Splashscreen}:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.LEEADS.timestableseasy.Splashscreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.LEEADS-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.LEEADS-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2192)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)  
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class  "com.LEEADS.timestableseasy.Splashscreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.LEEADS-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.LEEADS-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2183)
> ... 11 more
> ```

Comment: Add code where catch this exception

Comment: the problem with that is i have to wait about an hour to test it. as this only happened when getting the app from the store

Answer (score 1):

You use Proguard? Except from obfuscation all method's name that you call in `invoke()`

For example add to proguard.cfg:

```
-keep class com.mypackagename.myActivity {
   public static void myMethod( boolean, java.lang.String);
}
```

You must correct insert all parameters in method

Comment: i dont think i use proguard. should i be using it?

Comment: Are exist file 'proguard.cfg' and folder 'proguard' in your project's folder in workspace?

Comment: i cant find any folders like that so i'm gonna say i'm not using them

Answer (score 0):

FYI, an APK will act the same coming from teh Play store as if you deployed directly from your IDE or computer.

The Play store doesn't modify, add, or remove anything from your packaged app (APK).  In other words, the APK downloaded from the Play store is identical to the one you uploaded from your computer.

Having said that, I think you have not exported your libraries with you APK.  Looks like you have a library with LEEADS in it.

To fix this:
    1. Right click on your project
    2. Click 'Properties'
    3. Click 'Java Build Path'
    4. Select 'Order and Export' Tab
    5. Make sure there is a check-mark next to 'Android Private Libraries'

Comment: yeah i thought that it didn't which makes it more confusing that it doesn't work from the play store. the LEEADS is the packages names ie: "com.LEEADS.activity" so for some reason it seems to be looking for LEEADS-1

Comment: i'll try that but i cant see if it worked for about an hour. since i have to wait on google updating the APK

Comment: To be clear, you don't need to wait for the Play store to try your APK.  The APK you upload is the EXACT same, so you can test the output of your build.